# File isn't saved correctly

Tags: java, file, save, load

I am making a save/load feature for the settings in my application. Upon launching the program, it tries to find the file. If it fails, it tries to create a file with default settings (code below)

```
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(absolutePath))
        {
            fileWriter.write("theme=light\n");
            fileWriter.write("resolution=1280x720\n");
            fileWriter.write("printfps=false\n");

            System.out.println("Reset settings");
            load();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Settings File not found.");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

After it has written this, it goes on to load the file. (calling load() method)

In the load method, the application reads the contents of the file (code below).

```
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(absolutePath)))
        {
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            while(line != null)
            {
                if (line.contains("="))
                {
                    String key = line;
                    String value = line;

                    while (key.contains("="))
                    {
                        key = key.substring(0, key.length() - 1);
                    }

                    while (value.contains("="))
                    {
                        value = value.substring(1);
                    }

                    settings.put(key, value);
                }

                System.out.println(line);
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(settings);
        }
```

However, it returns that the file is empty. After messing with breakpoints, I can confirm that the file is indeed not updated at that point. The rather weird thing is that if I pause the application at a later time, the file seems to contain the text that was written to it, even though the file is not touched later in the program.

This makes me believe that it takes some time for the file to update, thus not updating in time for the load() method. Is this correct, or am I missing something? And is there a workaround?

All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `load()` before you actually saved the file.
To save the file, call `fileWriter.close()` or just move the `load()` call out of the `try-with-resource` block with the FileWriter:

```java
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(absolutePath))
        {
            fileWriter.write("theme=light\n");
            fileWriter.write("resolution=1280x720\n");
            fileWriter.write("printfps=false\n");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Settings File not found.");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // FileWriter closed now and the file contents saved
        System.out.println("Reset settings");
        load();
```